# How to prevent very big folder from /tmp/cargo-blah

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to install a package with cargo `cargo install wasm-pack`

```
[uname@fedora yew-app]$ cargo install wasm-pack
    Updating crates.io index
  Installing wasm-pack v0.9.1
   Compiling libc v0.2.95
   Compiling autocfg v1.0.1
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.27
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.2
error: failed to write `/tmp/cargo-installpGQzlC/release/.fingerprint/libc-90a06805c5b45af7/invoked.timestamp`

Caused by:
  No space left on device (os error 28)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `wasm-pack v0.9.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installpGQzlC`
```

It says that I don't have more space left, so I check my storage using `df` command and found out that my tmp folder is full caused by cargo.

```
[uname@fedora ~]$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
// ...other storage
tmpfs             967296  967296         0 100% /tmp
// ...other storage
```

[image]

This is tremendously big for just tmp files, how can I prevent this to happen in the future?

Comment: This happened to me in an old 32-bit installation that had a small `/tmp` tmpfs. To avoid that I sometimes used `mkdir -p $HOME/tmp; TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp cargo install ...`. Other times I just disabled the `tmpfs` mount in `/etc/fstab`, so that `/tmp` is a normal hard-disk directory, instead of a RAM device.